# If you are a language designer, how would you make ignoring parameters more succint for lambdas?

Tags: lambda, language-design

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505850/can-i-ignore-delegate-parameters-with-lambda-syntax), how would you make ignoring parameters more succint?

var m = menuStrip.Items.Add("Hello", null, delegate { MessageBox.Show("Como Esta Mundo"); });

I'm thinking along the lines of:

var m = menuStrip.Items.Add("Hello", null, ==> MessageBox.Show("Como Esta Mundo") );

var m = menuStrip.Items.Add("Hello", null, ? => MessageBox.Show("Como Esta Mundo") );

or perhaps this:

var m = menuStrip.Items.Add("Hello", null, ?=> MessageBox.Show("Como Esta Mundo") );

What would be your take?

<language evolution observation>
They even add ?? operator to the language, which is indeed beautiful. Now I think if they would like to make a converse of it (i.e. NullIf operator), this is very useful if you want to treat something as the same "" or zero is equal to null </language evolution observation>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just like anonymous methods, you'd have to know the compile-time type you were trying to convert the lambda expression to (unless C# starts supporting free functions, which is a bigger change).

I quite like ?=> though:

```
Action<int> foo = ?=> Console.WriteLine("Okay");
EventHandler handler = ?=> Console.WriteLine("Okay too");
```

Now as `ToolStripCollection.Add` specifically declares `EventHandler` as the delegate, your examples would be okay. This wouldn't though:

```
control.Invoke(?=> Console.WriteLine("No no no"));
```

Here the compiler wouldn't know which type to try to convert the lambda expression to, so it would require a cast - just like anonymous methods do today.