# Alternative for Task.Wait in UI thread

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, task-parallel-library, async-ctp

I know it is bad to call `Task.Wait` in UI thread. It causes a deadlock. Please refer to

[Constructor invoke async method](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winappswithcsharp/thread/0d24419e-36ad-4157-abb5-3d9e6c5dacf1)

[Await, and UI, and deadlocks! Oh my!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx)

Take the following code:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        step0();
        step1();
    }

    private async Task step0()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("step 0");
    }

    private async Task step1()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("step 1");
    }
}
```

How can I ensure that "step 0" is always being printed before "step 1"? Using `Task.Wait` would cause deadlock. **This is Windows Store App**

Comment: Deadlock is when two threads are trying to access data with a lock, so they end up waiting forever

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Actually, [`Wait` *does* cause a deadlock, as I explain in detail on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary, thanks. Comment about "Wait/Sleep does not cause "deadlock", both cause non-responsive UI" is deleted as wrong - sync completion of async task can cause real deadlock on if requires new thread and reporting back to original one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Task.ContinueWith` to chain the tasks together so that they happen sequentially.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    step0().ContinueWith(t => step1());
}
```

Also, Alexei's comment is correct.  `Task.Wait` will *block* the UI thread.  Deadlocks are something else.

Comment: Thanks. But I was curious. If `step0().ContinueWith(delegate{ step1(); });` is valid, why `step0().ContinueWith(() => step1());` doesn't valid?

Comment: As `fun(()=>System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hello"));` and `fun(delegate { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hello"); });` both workable.

Comment: [Answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505850/can-i-ignore-delegate-parameters-with-lambda-syntax)

Answer (score 5):

You can't have an `async` constructor, period.

So whatever you do, you'll need to handle the situation where your constructor returns *without* having completed its `async` initialization.

There are a few ways of handling this. If the "steps" are loading resources, then you can do something like this (using the [`AsyncLazy` type from my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html), [Stephen Toub's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/15/10116210.aspx), or my [AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/) - they're all nearly the same):

```
private readonly AsyncLazy<MyResource> resource;

public MainPage()
{
  resource = new AsyncLazy<MyResource>(async () =>
  {
    var a = await step0();
    var b = await step1();
    return new MyResource(a, b); // or whatever
  });
  resource.Start(); // start step0
}

public async Task MethodThatNeedsResource()
{
  var r = await resource; // ensure step1 is complete before continuing
}
```

It's also possible to do this with an `async void` method or `ContinueWith`, but you'll have to carefully consider error handling with those approaches.

- The `AsyncLazy` approach will capture errors and raise them whenever `await resource` is executed.
- The `async void` approach will throw errors immediately to the `SynchronizationContext`.
- The naive `ContinueWith` approach will silently ignore all errors.

Whichever approach you take, I recommend having some notification in the UI that the initialization is in progress. (And as a side note, I think all of this should go into a ViewModel or Model class rather than `MainPage`).