# Anonym functions only benefit against lambdas

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am still reading documentation about **C#** and I fell on [anonymous functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-methods).
It is true that they prioritize lambda expressions against it but,

they also said right after :

> There is one case in which an anonymous method provides functionality not found in lambda expressions. Anonymous methods enable you to omit the parameter list. This means that an anonymous method can be converted to delegates with a variety of signatures. This is not possible with lambda expressions.

This *(quotation)* is what I want to understand with some few examples if needed. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. My clipboard was contaning something else. I did not figure it out. I already changed the link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I ignore delegate parameters with lambda syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505850/can-i-ignore-delegate-parameters-with-lambda-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ignore the parameters in a delegate then with anonymous function syntax using `delegate` you can leave them out:

```
Action<int> a = delegate { Console.WriteLine("I am ignoring the int parameter."); }; //takes 1 argument, but not specified on the RHS
a(2); // Prints "I am ignoring the int parameter."
```

There is no way of doing this with lambda expressions:

```
Action<int> a = => { Console.WriteLine("I am ignoring the int parameter."); }; // syntax error

Action<int> a = () => { Console.WriteLine("I am ignoring the int parameter."); }; // CS1593 Delegate 'Action<int>' does not take 0 arguments
```

It's not terribly useful, but it can be a bit handy when you know you want something done on an event and don't even care what it's signature is.

```
button.OnClick += delegate { Console.WriteLine("Button clicked and that's all I care about"); };
```

Historically the big advantage anonymous functions had in C# 2.0 was that they existed. Lambda syntax didn't get introduced until C# 3.0.

Comment: Very funny on these last sentences. Thank you. You gave great explanation.

Comment: Funny but also a practical matter, in that if we had lambdas already they might not have bothered to put anonymous functions created through `delegate` at all, since they have relatively little advantage. Understanding that they didn't come about at the same time helps understand why they both exist.